# How to select different rows data in single column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with following structure,

```
ID      Date         Login     logout
644363  2014-07-02  11:18:00   11:29:00
644363  2014-07-02  11:55:00   12:17:00
644363  2014-07-02  12:17:00   12:24:00
644367  2014-07-02  15:25:00   15:42:00
644367  2014-07-02  15:45:00   15:59:00
644367  2014-07-02  16:15:00   16:38:00
```

This is login and logout timings table, How can i select first login time and last logout time for each ID.

Comment: do you mean min max of time or do you need to include date as well?

Comment: How it knows min and max time, if it integers it knows min value and max value but it's time.

Comment: @sandeep have you tried just using `min` and `max` like people have suggested? It works on more than just integers.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense I tried it but nothing selected.

Comment: @sandeep what was the specific query you used?

Answer (score 1):

A `GROUP BY` clause is probably what you need, with the `min` and `max` aggregates:

`SELECT min(login_time), max(logout_time) FROM this_table group by ID`

This will grab the minimum login time and maximum logout time for every single ID, returning each pair as a row.

Comment: Thanks @TheSoundDefense, I couldn't give more detail as I was on mobile. An upvote would be express even more gratefulness though?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, min(Login) as Earliest, Max(logout) as Latest
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
```

or if you need it by day...

```
SELECT ID, min(Login) as Earliest, Max(logout) as Latest, `date`
FROM table
GROUP BY ID, `date`
```

Comment: How it knows min and max time. anyway it doesn't select anything.

Comment: @sandeep `max` and `min` work just fine on normal SQL timestamps, as well as strings. In either case this should work. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL query might do the trick:

```
SELECT min(Login), max(logout)
FROM your_SQL_table group by ID
```